# Configuration of the gstreamer pipeline in the UWP app Windows

Tags: windows, uwp, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am using https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/seungha.yang/gst-uwp-example
and want to send a webcam video via Windows PC and receive it in UWP app and view it (later on HoloLens2). How to configure the transmitter and receiver?

I think with these lines from the gst-uwp-example you configure the receiver if I understand it correctly. But I don't know how exactly to configure it.

```
pipeline_ = gst_parse_launch( "videotestsrc ! queue ! d3d11videosink name=overlay", NULL);
GstElement* overlay = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline_), "overlay");
```

What does the configuration look like?

And how to send the webcam image through windows cmd?

Thanks a lot!